# Facebook Shop and Google Shopping Feed

Tags: magento2, facebook, google-product-feeds, google-shopping

I am looking to setup a Shop on my Facebook page where it has all the products from my site on Facebook. Also I want to setup a Google Shopping feed from our store with Selected Prodcuts (not all products, will vary depending from time to time), also for adwords, adsense, etc...
Will also want to do some Facebook sponsered ads of our products (select prodcuts as well)

I see many competitors has this setup and wondering the best option. I also see many extensions that claim to work for this and need somting that will cover everthing and with minimal time.

Answer (score 0):

To set up a Facebook Shop and Google Shopping Feed in Magento 2, you'll need to follow these steps:

Install and set up the Facebook Pixel and Facebook Catalog in your Magento 2 store. You can find more information on how to do this in the Magento 2 documentation.

Set up your Facebook Shop. To do this, you'll need to create a Facebook Business account and connect it to your Magento 2 store. You can then create a Facebook Shop and add products to it by linking your Facebook Catalog to your Facebook Shop.

Set up your Google Shopping Feed. To do this, you'll need to create a Google Merchant Center account and connect it to your Magento 2 store. You can then create a Google Shopping Feed and add products to it by linking your Google Merchant Center account to your Magento 2 store.

Optimize your product data for both Facebook and Google. This includes adding high-quality product images, accurate product titles and descriptions, and relevant product tags and categories.

Set up automatic product updates for your Facebook Shop and Google Shopping Feed. This will ensure that your products are always up-to-date on both platforms.

It's worth noting that setting up a Facebook Shop and Google Shopping Feed can be a complex process, and it may be helpful to seek the assistance of a Magento 2 developer if you're not comfortable with the steps involved.

Comment: Don't they have good Extensions to this with so that it is not so complex. If so what are some of the best to look at